# Desktop icon is not being shown properly

Tags: advanced-installer

I am using [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) to create the installer of java based desktop application, it is working fine. I added a desktop shortcut icon of the EXE, when i install the application on my system its desktop icon is correct as i defined when created the installer, but when i uninstall the app and then reinstall it 2nd or 3rd time sometimes its desktop icon get changed by itself(replaced with no icon).

can someone tell me what is the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is a sign of corrupted Windows Installer cache on your machine. Have you tried testing the package in a VM? The icons are cached by the OS in a special system folder, nothing special is done by the setup package or Advanced Installer in order for the icons to be set on the shortcuts.

Comment: I have to give some explanation to lead, can you plz help me in this regard... Your reason is looking valid but can you plz explain with some more details

Comment: Here is a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400472/wrong-desktop-shortcut-icon-on-windows-7-inno-setup